# How does this trimmer circuit work?

Tags: voltage, pcb, diodes, ac, dc

This question is going to be long...

[image: The trimmer][image: The adapter]

This is the trimmer and its adapter.

---

[image: the board]
[image: the board]

And this is the board inside the trimmer. On the left is the power source and on the right is a motor.

Since I don't know the name of the part inside the red circles, I'll just call them "terminals" for now.
[image]

Note that the trimmer is turned on when these two inside the red circles are shorted:
[image]

---

I thought at the beginning that the adapter outputs a DC voltage. But after measuring the output, I found that it outputs AC. The readings:

AC reading:

[image: AC reading]

DC reading:

[image: DC reading]

You can see that there is a diode on the board, I believe this is for converting the input AC voltage to half wave DC voltage. Here is the reading near the power source (before it passes through the diode) and between the two terminals where the battery will be put:

[image]

I've scratched the PCB a bit to get access to the metal inside it to be able to attach the alligator clips.

[image]

Note here that the reading in the first picture is an AC voltage whereas the second photo is DC.

I believe that the input voltage is an AC voltage and is converted to a half signal DC voltage using the diode. Another use for the diode would be to prevent the backwards current generated by the motor when the trimmer is turned off (I'm not sure). The voltage should look something like this:

[image]

To even support my claim, note that the led in the board takes an AC voltage (the current for the led does not pass through the diode), the led flickers a lot (can't be seen by the naked eye, but is very obvious when using the camera), moreover, the led ignites no matter which direction it's connected in. Here are some proof videos:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

**Flickering** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFbQqAMmkpo)

[[image: Video thumbnail]

**Both directions** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8ELywihD0c)

---

There are some stuff that happens that I don't know the reason for, for example:

1 - when the adapter is connected, the led is ignites. When then putting the battery, the led gets dimmer.

Video:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

**Led gets dimmer** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1JjmXx5D48)

2 - I read that both terminals of the motor are shorted. Is it because inside the motor is just a single wire in multiple loops? Or is there an another reason?

3 - When turning the trimmer on (by shorting the two parts in the red circles above) while connected only to the adapter, the light of the led goes down (which indicates that something is consuming other than the led), but nothing changes, I see no voltage across the motor.

Video:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

**Only the adapter is connected** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjQz9MVgxYI)

4 - When turning the trimmer on while connected to both the adapter and the battery, as opposed to number 3, I get a voltage across the motor which is about 1.2v (the voltage of the battery). I expected that the adapter will play a role in the voltage across the motor, but looks like it's not contributing there at all. It only affects the voltage across the two terminals, but not across the motor.

Video:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

**Both the adapter and the battery** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZJvgGD929Q)

5 - When measuring the voltage between the two terminals, the reading differs based on the position of the multimeter leads (you can see in the picture above that it's 5.79, but in the video below, it's about 6.60), also the reading increases a lot when I touch the two leads of the multimeter.

Video:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

**Different position / touching** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mioy15n3DsY)

---

Questions are:

1. Is the input to the board actually an AC and is converted to DC using the diode? Does it make sense? is the input voltage that charge the battery actually a half wave voltage?
2. Is there other job for the diode other than converting AC to DC? for example, blocking the backwards current caused by the motor when the trimmer is turned off.
3. Why does the led get dimmer when the battery is inserted?
4. Why doesn't the motor work when the board is only connected to the adapter (without the battery)? Why when both the adapter and the battery are connected, all I see across the motor is only the voltage of the battery?
5. Why do I read that both terminals of the motor are shorted. Is it because inside the motor is just a single wire in multiple loops? Or is there an another reason?
6. Why when only the adapter is connected, when turning on, the led gets dimmer, but nothing else happens? I expected the motor to start spinning.
7. How does an input voltage (from the adapter) of 3.81v AC gets converted by the diode to +5v DC? How did the voltage increase?
8. Why does the voltage change when the position of the leads is different or when I touch the leads?

Comment: draw a schematic diagram of the device ... include the transformer in the schematic ... consider how much current is drawn by the motor ... think about the amount of current that can be provided by the transformer and by the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend drawing this out as a schematic to make sense of it.

[image: hand drawn schematic]

> Is the input to the board actually an AC and is converted to DC using the diode? Does it make sense? is the input voltage that charge the battery actually a half wave voltage?

An AC power supply is simpler, it's just a transformer. So you do see them sometimes when cost is a major factor.

> Is there other job for the diode other than converting AC to DC? for example, blocking the backwards current caused by the motor when the trimmer is turned off.

Based on the schematic I would call that a rectifier.

> Why does the led get dimmer when the battery is inserted?

The wall wart is a simple unregulated transformer, so the voltage sags heavily when a load is added. The battery is either charging, or fully charged and just dissipating the excess power as heat.

> Why doesn't the motor work when the board is only connected to the adapter (without the battery)? Why when both the adapter and the battery are connected, all I see across the motor is only the voltage of the battery?

The adapter probably cannot supply enough current to turn the motor. The voltage simply sags to nothing if you try. The battery can put out much more current.

> Why do I read that both terminals of the motor are shorted. Is it because inside the motor is just a single wire in multiple loops? Or is there an another reason?

They aren't actually shorted. The motor just has a low resistance. The multimeter will beep for anything less than say 10 ohms.

> Why when only the adapter is connected, when turning on, the led gets dimmer, but nothing else happens? I expected the motor to start spinning.

The motor is pulling the voltage down to a point where the motor cannot turn, but there is still enough voltage to light the LED.

> How does an input voltage (from the adapter) of 3.81v AC gets converted by the diode to +5v DC? How did the voltage increase?

The voltage didn't actually increase. When you read the voltage in AC mode, the RMS voltage is displayed. This is sort of like the average voltage, and not the peak. When you measure the rectified DC voltage you get the peak voltage - the diode drop.

> Why does the voltage change when the position of the leads is different or when I touch the leads?

Because of the diodes, the voltage drops throughout the circuit. The power supply also sags whenever there is even a small load. If the circuit had some regulators you would see stable voltages as the conditions varied. Because it has none, the voltages will change whenever the conditions change.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. And sorry for the misleading question (number 8). In number 8, I measure the same positions on the board (the terminals), but the position of the LEADS is what actually have changed (i.e. when I hold the leads or when I leave them on the desk).

Comment: Also, why does the voltage read increases when I connect the two leads with my finger?